# preg_match_all returning 2 results

Tags: php, regex

```
$string = "c4414b8e90510db12 GET /emailtrack/blank.gif?source=mailchimp&guid=12345&campaign=myCampaign HTTP/1.1"
preg_match_all('/("GET.*?"+)/is',$string,$match);

Result:

Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [0] => "GET /emailtrack/blank.gif?source=mailchimp&guid=12345&campaign=myCampaign HTTP/1.1"
    )

    [1] => Array (
        [0] => "GET /emailtrack/blank.gif?source=mailchimp&guid=12345&campaign=myCampaign HTTP/1.1"
    )
)
```

Parsing the string through `preg_match_all` just to fetch the GET String but it returns 2 results of GET string, I only need one result in the array

Thanks for the earlier answer it worked for me.

```
$string = "source=xxxx&campaign=asdas&guid=121"
```

Is there anyways you can help me with telling me a regex for extracting just the source=xxxxx from the string above

I tried this

```
preg_match_all('/source.*?\s/', $string, $match);
```

But it gives me the entire string ,I want to separate the strings source, campaign & guid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first entry of the result is always the full match. You also have additional parentheses around the entire pattern, which is becoming the first "subpattern".

Solution: Remove the parentheses.